# How i can disable access to my local machine form another local machine by \\ip address\c$?

Tags: security, ip, administrator, ip-address, local

Someone in the same local network here has user full control administration he can enter to my partitions D, C, E all partitions by type  in start menu `\\my IP address\c$` he can copying  and delete my files.

How can I stop this?

Comment: What kind of network is it? Home or Office?

Comment: Do you have admin rights on the machine?

Comment: my problem is about someone in my job in the same network he can access my local machine like this \\ my ip address \C$

Comment: after he type \\ my ip address \C$ he can  copy any file from my machine and remove any file in any time  he have admin user ,adminstration user

Comment: Yes drives are shared by windows automatically and you can't stop that from happening without having an administrator account on the machine.

Comment: "someone in my job in the same network" then you should speak to your IT department about this (especially if you have confidential information on your PC. Note that issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off topic, see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: i,m in iT department my colleague he can enter to my computer

Comment: If this person can access your c$, that person has admin rights to your machine.  Is this person an admin in your company?

Answer (score 1):

If you are an admin user you could disable through `computer management`

Right click my computer-->manage ;

[image]

Since I have one partition ( C drive), it is shared with $ mark. To disable this default admin share, simply right click on partition and select stop sharing.

[image]

Hope it helps
Piccredits : Sysprobs

Comment: Do note, a network administrator will be able to enable this again. But then again, someone with the rights and the knowledge cannot be stopped anyway.

Comment: The share will be made available again after a reboot.To completely disable it you'll need to edit the registry. This can also conflict with some windows services.